# Making a ggplot boxplot where each column is it's own boxplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, boxplot

when using the simple R boxplot function, I can easily place my dataframe directly into the parenthesis and a perfect boxplot emerges, eg:

```
baseline <- c(0,0,0,0,1)
post_cap <- c(1,5,5,6,11)
qx314 <- c(0,0,0,3,7)
naive_capqx <- data.frame(baseline, post_cap, qx314)
boxplot(naive_capqx)
```

[this is an image of the boxplot made with the simple R boxplot function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZrEx.png)

However, I need to make this boxplot slightly more aesthetic and so I need to use ggplot. When I place the dataframe itself in, the boxplot cannot form as I need to specify x, y and fill coordinates, which I don't have. My y coordinates are the values for each vector in the dataframe and my x coordinates are just the name of the vector. How can I do this using ggplot? Is there a way to reform my dataframe so I can split it into coordinates, or is there a way ggplot can read my data?

Answer (score 2):

`geom_boxplot` expects [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data.  Your data isn't tidy because the column names contain information.  So the first thing to do is to tidy your data by using `pivot_longer`...

```
library(tidyverse)

naive_capqx %>%  
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_to="Value", names_to="Variable") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=Variable, y=Value))
```

giving

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried using this code but my R cannot decipher %>%. Is this a separate package I may not have loaded?

Comment: `%>%` is part of the [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) package, which is contained in the tidyverse meta-package.  My code is a MWE and should run as-is.  You can avoid using `%>%` if you wish by replacing `naive_capqx %>% pivot_longer(everything()...` with `pivot_longer(naive_capqx, everything()...`.  Note that @RebeccaAmodeo's solution, whilst correct, uses `gather()`, which has been superseded by the `pivot_XXXX` functions..

Answer (score 1):

Turn the df into a long format df. Below, I use `gather()` to lengthen the df; I use `group_by()` to ensure boxplot calculation by key (formerly column name).

```
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, tidyverse)

baseline <- c(0,0,0,0,1)
post_cap <- c(1,5,5,6,11)
qx314 <- c(0,0,0,3,7)

naive_capqx <- data.frame(baseline, post_cap, qx314) %>%
  gather("key", "value")) %>%
  group_by(key)
  

ggplot(naive_capqx, mapping = aes(x = key, y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: hi, sorry but what does %>% mean? my R cannot understand it!

Comment: Hi @NuritEliana, thanks for asking! It is an operator called the "pipe". It sends whatever is before (to the left of it) and sends it onto the next command. It eliminates the need to enter the `data` argument in the command that follows it because R will know that the object before the pipe is what you want to use as the `data` argument. I think of it as like saying to R "and then". It was originally in the `magrittr` package and is included in `dplyr` and `tidyverse` packages and in R 4.1. It saves a lot of typing! A [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiF_p6iAitE). Hope that helps!